# Parse JSON response in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm building an app using AngularJS and I am trying to plot locations on a google map. I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```
 locations: [{ 
    id: 123
    latlng:  { 
        lat: 56.3
        lon: -2.1
        } 
    name: TestName
    }]
```

The directive I'm using ([angular-google-maps](http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/usage)) requires the markers to be in the below format. What I would like to do is to create a new array containing only the lat and lng values, that looks like this. I also need to rename the lat and lng to longitude and latitude:

```
markers: [ {
        latitude: 45,
        longitude: -74
    },{
        latitude: 46,
        longitude: -75  
    }]
```

I'm new to programming, especially in javascript. I tried to see if I can access the latlng object in the JSON response, but get undefined. Here is what that looks like:

```
for (var latlng in $scope.locations) {
        if ($scope.locations.hasOwnProperty(latlng))
        {
            var latitude = $scope.locations[latlng].lat;
        }
        console.log(latitude);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's better to iterate over indices rather than keys if you have an _Array_. `var i, latlng; for (i = 0; i < $scope.locations.length; ++i) {latlng = $scope.locations[i]; /* etc */}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.locations[latlng]` gets you to the object containing the latlng key, not the object referred to by that key. Since the iteration variable is an index into the array, you'll find it less confusing to use a name that reflects this, e.g., `i` instead of `latlng`:

```
for (var i in $scope.locations) {
    …
    var latitude = $scope.locations[i].latlng.lat;
    …
}
```

In most JavaScript implementations, you have another option:

```
$scope.locations.forEach(function(location) {
    …
    var latitude = location.latlng.lat;
    …
});
```

(Also note @rtcherry's comment.)

Comment: I would suggesting using either `angular.forEach` or a library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/) to provide utility functions such as `forEach`.  `Array.forEach` was introduced with JavaScript 1.6, which is not supported by some legacy browsers.  Example: `angular.forEach($scope.locations, function(location) { ... });`